# Display code in appropriate #ifdef block according to the value of identifier

Tags: vim, ctags, conditional-compilation, exuberant-ctags

I have a C codebase with source files using #ifdef blocks all over. There are multiple identifiers and corresponding ifdefs (with the ifdefs nested to multiple levels). While viewing the code in `vim`, is there a way for me to define multiple identifiers and view/highlight my code such that I see only those ifdef blocks which are applicable when an identifier is defined.

```
#if defined(ID1) && (ID1 == 1)
// code 1
#elif defined(ID1) && (ID1 == 2)
// code 2
```

When set `ID=1`, my view should only display/highlight `code 1`, when `ID=2` my view should only display/highlight `code 2`, otherwise if `ID` is not defined, both `code 1` and `code 2` should not be highlighted or displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DISCLAIMER

This is generally a bad idea. You never want to hide text in a source file. 
Compiling different code branches based on flags set at compile time is a 
different story. But viewing the code, you should always see what you ask 
the compiler to build
```

That said, if you want to hide code when reading, there are a couple ways you can achieve that

1. **Fold it**: See `:help fold` for more details
2. **Syntax**: [junegunn/limelight.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/limelight.vim) is a good tool to selectively turn off syntax highlighting for code spaces outside the region your cursor is in.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly functional solution for folding C++.

First setup general ifdef folding. This should catch `#if`, `#ifdef`, and `#ifndef`:

```
function! FoldtextForC()
    " Show the whole #if line
    return getline(v:foldstart)
endfun
set foldtext=FoldtextForC()
set foldmarker=#if,#endif
```

Then you could do something like this to close all the `DEBUG` folds:

```
:g/#ifdef DEBUG/foldclose
```

After running that command [this code sample](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/98b1cc82c4affc16f5598d4fa14b1858671b2263/fs/efs/super.c#L178-L233) will look like this (`set foldcolumn=3` so you can see the folding):

[image: some linux code folded]

You'd probably want to write something smarter that does `:foldopen!`, collects all the defines, separates into defined and undefined, builds the appropriate regex, and does the above command with your improved regex.

---

The alternative is to write a `'foldexpr'` that does something similar but only folds blocks that are not compiled. Then you can always `:foldclose!` to hide everything that's not compiled and `:foldopen!` to see everything again.